# system of differential-algebraic equation

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I solve the differential -algebraic equations and I got the result. I have 
no problem for this point. My problem at the end when I need to find the sum of the four solutions. u[0,t]+u[1,t]+u[2,t]+u[3,t].

```
 H1 := 
 \!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0, t] - 0.7071067811865475` 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[1, t] - 2.7755575615628914`*^-17 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[2, t] + 0.7071067811865477` 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[3, t] - (-0.04549512883486596` E^-t + 
0.46266352733266075` (u[2, t] - 4.242640687119286` u[3, t]))

H2 := +
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[0, t] + 0.7071067811865475` 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[1, t] - 0.7071067811865444` 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[3, t] - (1.5454951288348655` E^-t + 
11.047340291170295` (u[2, t] + 4.242640687119284` u[3, t]))

B1 := u[0, t] - u[1, t] + u[2, t] - u[3, t]

B2 := u[0, t] + u[1, t] + u[2, t] + u[3, t]



sol = DSolve[{H1 == 0, H2 == 0, B1 == 0, B2 == 0, u[0, 0] == 0.0625`, 
u[1, 0] == 0.031249999999999997`} , {u[0, t], u[1, t], u[2, t], 
u[3, t]}, t] // Flatten


Evaluate[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(3\)]\(u[i, t]\)\) /.      
 sol[[1]]]
```

My problem here.  u[1, t] + u[2, t] + u[3, t] did not take the values of it. I would help here. Thanks

```
  -0.01347633839516044 E^(-24.02000763765244 t) (-0.8509159183836982 E^(
  1.686576282750643 t) - 
  4.786842363391539 E^(23.02000763765244 t) + 
  1. E^(23.33343135490179 t)) + u[1, t] + u[2, t] + u[3, t]
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer  is

```
Evaluate[\!\(
\*UnderoverscriptBox[\(\[Sum]\), \(i = 0\), \(3\)]\(u[i, t]\)\) /. 
sol[[1]]] /. sol
```

I have mistake  when I wrote sol[[1]].

```
 0. + 0.01347633839516044 E^(-24.02000763765244 t) \
 (-0.8509159183836981 E^(1.686576282750643 t) - 
 4.786842363399974 E^(23.02000763765244 t) + 
 1. E^(23.33343135490179 t)) - 
 0.01347633839516044 E^(-24.02000763765244 t) (-0.8509159183836982 E^(
 1.686576282750643 t) - 
 4.786842363391539 E^(23.02000763765244 t) + 
 1. E^(23.33343135490179 t))
```